# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space error in my code

Tags: java, json, eclipse, io, amazon-s3

I am trying to read a JSON File and do some operations. This JSON file is in `Amazon S3` and it is 500MB in size. Future files will be in TeraBytes. Below is my code.

```
public void createHash() throws IOException
    {
        System.out.println("Hash Creation Started");

        strBuffer = new StringBuffer("");


        try
        {
            //List all the Buckets
            List<Bucket>buckets = s3.listBuckets();

            for(int i=0;i<buckets.size();i++)
            {
                System.out.println("- "+(buckets.get(i)).getName());
            }


            //Downloading the Object
            System.out.println("Downloading Object");
            S3Object s3Object = s3.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(inputBucket, inputFile));
            System.out.println("Content-Type: "  + s3Object.getObjectMetadata().getContentType());


            //Read the JSON File
            /*BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s3Object.getObjectContent()));
            while (true) {
                String line = reader.readLine();
                if (line == null) break;

               // System.out.println("    " + line);
                strBuffer.append(line);

            }*/

            JSONTokener jTokener = new JSONTokener(new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s3Object.getObjectContent())));
            jsonArray = new JSONArray(jTokener);

            System.out.println("Json array length: "+jsonArray.length());


            for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++)
            {
                JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                StringBuffer hashIndex = new StringBuffer("");

                //Add Title and Body Together to the list
                String titleAndBodyContainer = jsonObject1.getString("title")+" "+jsonObject1.getString("body");


                //Remove full stops and commas
                titleAndBodyContainer = titleAndBodyContainer.replaceAll("\\.(?=\\s|$)", " ");
                titleAndBodyContainer = titleAndBodyContainer.replaceAll(",", " ");
                titleAndBodyContainer = titleAndBodyContainer.toLowerCase();


                //Create a word list without duplicated words
                StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

                HashSet<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
                for(String s : titleAndBodyContainer.split(" ")) {
                    if (!set.contains(s)) {
                        result.append(s);
                        result.append(" ");
                        set.add(s);
                    }
                }
                //System.out.println(result.toString());


                //Re-Arranging everything into Alphabetic Order
                String testString = "acarpous barnyard gleet diabolize acarus creosol eaten gleet absorbance";
                //String testHash = "057        1$k     983    5*1      058     52j    6!v   983     03z";

                String[]finalWordHolder = (result.toString()).split(" ");
                Arrays.sort(finalWordHolder);


                //Navigate through text and create the Hash
                for(int arrayCount=0;arrayCount<finalWordHolder.length;arrayCount++)
                {


                    if(wordMap.containsKey(finalWordHolder[arrayCount]))
                    {
                        hashIndex.append((String)wordMap.get(finalWordHolder[arrayCount]));
                    }

                }

                //System.out.println(hashIndex.toString().trim());

                jsonObject1.put("hash_index", hashIndex.toString().trim()); //Add the Hash to the JSON Object
                jsonObject1.put("primary_key", i); //Create the primary key
                jsonObjectHolder.add(jsonObject1); //Add the JSON Object to the JSON collection

                jsonHashHolder.add(hashIndex.toString().trim());

                System.out.println("JSON Number: "+i);

                //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(finalWordHolder));
                //System.out.println("- "+hashIndex.toString());

                //break;

            }

            System.out.println("Hash Creation Completed");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

But, I get the following error when the code is executed.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2894)
        at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.expandCapacity(AbstractStringBuilder.java:117)
        at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:589)
        at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:337)
        at com.amazonaws.util.json.JSONTokener.nextString(JSONTokener.java:284)
        at com.amazonaws.util.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:348)
        at com.amazonaws.util.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:222)
        at com.amazonaws.util.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:351)
        at com.amazonaws.util.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:125)
        at HashCreator.createHash(HashCreator.java:215)
        at HashCreator.<init>(HashCreator.java:61)
        at Main.main(Main.java:9)
[root@ip-172-31-45-123 JarFiles]#
```

It talks about line number 215, and it is this code - `jsonArray = new JSONArray(jTokener);`

What is happening here and how can I solve this?

**Edit**

This is my JSON code:

```
[
    {
        "hash_index": "00102x05h06l0aj0dw",
        "body": "Who's signing up for Obamacare?",
        "_type": "ArticleItem",
        "title": "Who's signing up for Obamacare? - Jan. 13, 2014",
        "source": "money.cnn.com",
        "primary_key": 0,
        "last_crawl_date": "2014-01-14",
        "url": "http://money.cnn.com/2014/01/13/news/economy/obamacare-enrollment/index.html"
    },
    {
        "hash_index": "00102x05h06l0aj0dw0iz0kn0l@0t#0",
        "body": "Who's signing up for Obamacare?",
        "_type": "ArticleItem",
        "title": "Who's signing up for Obamacare? - Jan. 13, 2014",
        "source": "money.cnn.com",
        "primary_key": 1,
        "last_crawl_date": "2014-01-14",
        "url": "http://money.cnn.com/2014/01/13/news/economy/obamacare-enrollment/index.html"
    }
]
```

Anyway, please don't provide me the solution "increase your heap size". It is not a solution, it is a "plaster".

Comment: The file is just one big JSON object?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: Hi, it is a Big JSON file. It is a JSON Array.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: Please have a look at the edit. You can understand :)

Comment: Does reading line-by-line work without running out of memory? I would probably do that, and use a different JSON parser (one that doesn't read everything in memory).

Comment: @ThomasMueller: I don't know. Maybe GSON? I have never used any of these anyway.

Comment: Does reading line-by-line work without running out of memory?

Comment: @ThomasMueller: Now I am using GSON. Seems like it has solved the issue. Will update you :)

Answer (score 0):

just increase your heap size:

```
java -Xmx2g myprogram
```

Comment: OP should note that 2g is the size of memory, change based on what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

The heap is where object instances are stored.  Consider your program scope, try to see if you're creating instances that are being held onto within scope.  This holds true for the method that invoked your createHash(), it may be holding on to it's own objects in it's scope.

If you're running out of heap, that could indicate lots of objects are being created somewhere, and maybe stored in a list or other data structure that is holding on to them and preventing the garbage collector from cleaning shop.

Increasing your heap size would help, but it may only delay the problem.